# I can't boot from a USB stick and I want to install Ubuntu on my computer. How do I fix it?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, usb, windows-8.1

I have a Dell Inspiron 5520 with Windows 8.1 x64 and I want to install Ubuntu as a secondary OS. Earlier, I have tried installing JoliOS Express with the *.exe package and it said It was missing a file called winbuidr.mbr or something like it (Probably because I have UEFI BIOS Mode). My main question:

> How do I install Ubuntu from a USB drive while my USB Port is not a boot location? How can I make it a boot location?
>
> Computer Info:
>
> - DELL Inspiron 5520
> - Windows 8.1
> - x64 Build
> - Intel Core i7 @ 2.20 GHz
> - BIOS Version: A14
> - BIOS Mode: UEFI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press <kbd>F12</kbd> during the BIOS sequence, there should be an option to boot from a removable drive.

---

Edit: I found [this thread](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19469063.aspx), that should have a solution. You can also refer to [this askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/257405/51142).

Comment: Not really the problem. I actually do that but I don't see a USB choice. I've even tried the advanced boot from PC Settings>Update and Recovery>Recovery. Then, I choose the EFI USB. It will say, NO BOOT CHOICE FOUND.

Comment: On my XPS 15 (L502x) it's not called 'USB drive' but 'removable storage' or something similar.

Comment: updated answer with http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19469063.aspx

Comment: I might even try disabling the W2G Input setting.

Comment: W2G = Windows to Go

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to boot into the BIOS and change the boot order. Usually moving the specific device in question to the top will make it try and boot from that device first and then go down the list.

I had to turn off UEFI Safe Boot to get things to work as I would consider normal.

Comment: Do you have this computer? Exact model (Inspiron 5520)?

Answer (score 0):

1. Restart the PC with the USB plugged in, when the Dell logo appears, hit F2 till the BIOS menu opens.
2. Go on Boot Sequence, you need to ensure the BIOS is set to UEFI, disable Legacy option ROMS and check that secure boot is enabled on the Secure Boot Enable line.
3. Go to Boot Sequence

   3.1 Click on Add Boot Option. The Add Boot Option window will pop up. Type a name in the Boot Option Name text area ("Ubuntu", for example).

   3.2 Click the button to the left of the File Name text area. The EFI Boot Selection window will pop up.

   3.3 In the File System drop down menu choose FS0: and EFI. Then using the directories section, navigate until you can choose SHIMx64.EFI (for Ubuntu only - for other distros use grubx64.efi or grubx.efi if your PC is not amd64, anyway it will be named grubxxxxx.efi) in the Files section.

   A new boot option will now appear
4. Now in the boot sequence move the newly created "Ubuntu" Boot option to the top of the options. Save and exit

The laptop will now restart and show the boot menu